# mongodb aggregation lookup pipeline match $lte

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need a bit help understanding how to match in the lookup pipeline.
Here my aggregation.

```
 {$match: {$and: [
    {pairAddress: '0x8968cebff66c1188fbB28a7F6F2F0994a8aB3Be2'},
    {$or: [
        {timestamp: {$lte: 0, $ne: 0}},
        {timestamp: {$gte: 0}}
    ]}
]}},


{$addFields:{
    timestampBoundary: {
        $subtract: [
            "$timestamp",
            {$mod: ["$timestamp", 60]}
        ]
    },
}},

{$sort: {timestamp: 1}},

{$group:{
    _id: "$timestampBoundary",
    quoteTokenDecimals: {$last: "$quoteTokenDecimals"},
    base0: {$last: "$base0"},
    high: {$max: "$price"},
    low: {$min: "$price"},
    open: { $first: "$price" },
    close: { $last: "$price" },
    lastTime: {$last: "$timestamp"},
    amount: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$base0", true] },
                {$toDecimal: "$amount1"},
                {$toDecimal: "$amount0"}
            ]
        }
    },
    stable: {$last: "$stable"},
}},


{$lookup:{
    from: "BASEPRICE_BSC",
    let:{ timestampBoundary: "$timestampBoundary" },
    pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
                $lte: ["$timestampBoundary", "$$timestampBoundary"]
            }
        }},
        {$sort: { timestamp: 1 }},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: { _id: 0, price: 1}}
    ],
    as: "lookupResult"
}},


{$addFields:{
    conversionRate: {
      $cond: [
        { $eq: [{ $size: "$lookupResult" }, 0] },
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$lookupResult", -1] },
        { $arrayElemAt: ["$lookupResult", 0] }
      ]
    }
}},


{$project: {
    txs: 1,
    quoteTokenDecimals: 1,
    base0: 1,
    open: 1,
    high: 1,
    low: 1,
    close: 1,
    amount: 1,
    stable: 1,
    conversionRate: "$conversionRate.price"
}}
```

My aggregation create candlestick date from transactions. the open, close, high and low price is in relative price to the pair. I have another collection where I save conversion rate (BASEPRICE_BSC) the problem I am having that there won't be an exact match for for each candle with the timestamp from the baseprice collection. what I need it to find the nearest lower timestamp and use that as baseprice, but I can't get it to work.

What I not fully understand is the variable in the lookup pipeline and then the $expr with $lte array.

I know I want to create and array of all timestamps in the lookup matching the 'lastTime' timestamp lower then or equal to from the group sort is descending and return the first value. but I have no idea nor can I find any info on what exactly the let variable does or how to select a a field from the lookup collection in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like chat ai becoming better then using stack overflow.
After 3 days searching and testing, I finally got the info I need.

first in the group I add a new field "lastTime" which represents the highest number timestamp in the group.

then in the lookup I set that as external variable and can match where timestamp is greater then or equal to lasTime.

this will now always return a baseprice nearest to the timestamp I need.

```
{$match: {$and: [
    {pairAddress: '0x8968cebff66c1188fbB28a7F6F2F0994a8aB3Be2'},
    {$or: [
        {timestamp: {$lte: 0, $ne: 0}},
        {timestamp: {$gte: 0}}
    ]}
]}},


{$addFields:{
    timestampBoundary: {
        $subtract: [
            "$timestamp",
            {$mod: ["$timestamp", 60]}
        ]
    },
}},

{$sort: {timestamp: 1}},

{$group:{
    _id: "$timestampBoundary",
    quoteTokenDecimals: {$last: "$quoteTokenDecimals"},
    base0: {$last: "$base0"},
    high: {$max: "$price"},
    low: {$min: "$price"},
    open: { $first: "$price" },
    close: { $last: "$price" },
    lastTime: {$last: "$timestamp"},
    amount: {
        $sum: {
            $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$base0", true] },
                {$toDecimal: "$amount1"},
                {$toDecimal: "$amount0"}
            ]
        }
    },
    stable: {$last: "$stable"},
}},


{$lookup:{
    from: "BASEPRICE_BSC",
    let:{ lastTime: "$lastTime" },
    pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
                $gte: ["$timestamp", "$$lastTime"]
            }
        }},
        {$sort: { timestamp: 1}},
        {$limit: 1},
        {$project: { _id: 0, price: 1, timestamp: 1}}
    ],
    as: "lookupResult"
}},


{$addFields: {
    conversionRate: { $arrayElemAt: ["$lookupResult.price", 0] }
}},


{$project: {
    txs: 1,
    quoteTokenDecimals: 1,
    base0: 1,
    open: 1,
    high: 1,
    low: 1,
    close: 1,
    amount: {
        $toString: {
          $divide: [
            { $toDecimal: "$amount" },
            { $pow: [10, "$quoteTokenDecimals"] }
          ]
        }
    },
    stable: 1,
    conversionRate: 1,
    pairAddress: pairAddress,
}}
```

from chatGPT I got most of the solution but did not understand how the lookup pipeline works, let:{ lastTime: "$lastTime" }, we create a variable with a value from outside the lookup which we can use to compare inside the lookup.
$expr we need to use inside the match to compare fields inside lookup.